# Virtual Keyboard does not restore height of the viewport to its initial when closed

Tags: reactjs, webview, telegram-bot, viewport

I build telegram mini-apps using React. It uses web view to display apps in the telegram.
Telegram is like whatsup(who doesn't know).

I stumbled upon this issue, repro steps:

1. Create a bunch of inputs
2. Click on the last one
3. The keyboard appears and the screen scrolls to the focused input
4. When the keyboard is closed the viewport is not restored to its initial size and the black empty space can be seen in the bottom of the screen.

How can I fix it?

Default View

[image]

Opened keyboard and focused input is being scrolled to

[image]

Keyboard is closed and black space can be seen

[image]

```
    <div className="bg-white h-[100vh] overflow-hidden relative flex flex-col gap-10">
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="test" className="bg-red-300" />
</div>
```

Comment: The video you posted is private

Comment: However I think this is the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963400/android-keyboard-shrinking-the-viewport-and-elements-using-unit-vh-in-css. It's not mentioned in the answers there (probably because its a newer web feature) but i'd also try using the `dvh` unit instead `vh` on the container div which *might* be a nice and easy fix. If not, the existing answers should suffice.